# Xamarin trying to get users from webservice, immediate crash

Tags: c#, json, redis, servicestack, xamarin

Hi again stackoverflow,

I am following a tutorial on how to build an Android application in Xamarin and I have encountered an error I cannot resolve on my own. 
Hoping anyone of you might shed some light on how to proceed from here:

This code is copied from the tutorial itself (source: pluralsight)

```
private JsonServiceClient client;
private IList<User> users;

void PopulateSelectUsers ()
    {
        var response = client.Get(new Users());
        users = response.Users.ToList ();

        var names = users.Select (u => u.Name);

        var usersSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.usersSpinner);
        usersSpinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, names.ToArray ());
    }
```

Where "**Users**" is a request:

```
public object Get(Users request)
{
    return new UsersResponse { Users = Repository.GetUsers() };
}

[Route("/users", "GET")]
public class Users : IReturn<UsersResponse>
{
}

public class UsersResponse
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

HOWEVER once Xamarin read this line of code:

```
var response = client.Get(new Users());
```

then the application in the emulator just crashes and Xamarin leaves me no information on what happened or how to fix it..

It seems that this code works in the tutorial and as I mentioned before, Xamarin leaves me no information on what happened or how to fix it, so my question would be if perhaps one of you know what Is happening or perhaps a way to fix it.

Also perhaps worth mentioning is that I'm using redis to store users.

**IF you want to view the userservice** it is available here:
http://shan13alwo.cloudapp.net/api/metadata
You can check if code works by sending JSON GET to http://shan13alwo.cloudapp.net/api/users

Thank you in advance,

UPDATE:
I realize I might have been unclear of what I wanted to do but to simplify. What I want to do Is get my users(ienumerable) from my redis database and store them in a List. Using the this code in Xamarin does not work:

`var response = client.Get(new Users());
users = response.Users.ToList ();`

Comment: Have you setup the client connection before the call? `client = new JsonServiceClient("http://host:8080/");`

Comment: Hi @Scott and yes.
This line is also part of the code:
`client = new JsonServiceClient("http://shan13alwo.cloudapp.net/api");`

Everything in the tutorial is followed to point and if i comment out the PopulateSelectUsers () function, then it works.

Comment: What happens if you setup the project as a plain console app, without running it on Android?

Comment: Also this example returns a string of json data correctly:

`client = new JsonServiceClient("http://shan13alwo.cloudapp.net/api");
var response = client.Get<string> ("users");
Console.WriteLine (response);`

Comment: Sorry Scott, not sure im following. Do you mean a console app in Xamarine or in Visual Studio?

The project works and by sending GETS with google rest console or manually going to http://shan13alwo.cloudapp.net/api/users works wonders..

Comment: What I mean is, if you make a new Console Application in either Xamarin of Visual Studio (your choice, it doesn't matter). Then add the references to the ServiceStack REST client. Then make the connection and try your populate method.

Comment: Using a console application rather than the Android app will allow you to determine if there is a problem with the `JsonServiceClient` and ensure there are no errors with your service, before you try getting it running on Android.

Comment: I have created the Console App (http://pastebin.com/44cLr8Vh) and can confirm the issue isn't with the `JsonServiceClient`, given that your usage is similar. Perhaps instead of quoting the tutorial parts, include your complete code so it's possible to step through it.

Comment: Thank you again, So much @Scott for your assistance.

looked at your code and it seems to be working as it should. I have uploaded the Xamarin Solution here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tohktpd7vlx8ghv/xamarinsolution.7z

and Visual Studio Solution here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/smy8862x4a1elj9/VSsolution.7z

And again: I have no idea how to begin thanking you for your help through all this. I've learned ALOT.

Comment: I am going to post an update on my issue here:

I put a breakpoint in Xamarin studio where the appliaction suddenly crashes and I think I have found something.

When reaching the breakpoint I get the message that:

`MVCTest.Api.Users  Unknown identifier: MVCTest` 

I think there is something wrong with the namespaces since the UserResponses is in another .CS (class) file, with a link from Xamarin Studio from Visual Studio. 

If anyone has any suggestions, please?
Yours sincerely,

Comment: Ok moving the user responses inside the main .CS file did not change anything unfortunately.. :(
Any help greatly appreciated. still struggeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott previously pointed out to me In another topic made here on Stackoverflow: 
ServiceStack v4 was JUST released and using different versions of the servicestack library in Xamarin and Visual Studio resulted in this strange behavior.

Reverting back to V3 of ServiceStack solved my issues.

I would like to thank Scott for your assistance and would like to ask one last thing:
Where can I download the VERSION 3, free license version of the ServiceStack libraries for Android? 
(Think its called "AndroidIndie")
Downloading and compiling the solution with the libraries from the lib folder of ServiceStack results in "evaluation software, build valid for 24 hours".

Thank you in advance.